# Langchain Data extraction after chat

Tags: langchain

I need to extract structured data from a text. However, this structured data is too complex to be extracted using a single prompt, and hence I need to guide the model to solve some imprecisions (such as: "look, you have not considered this specific case").

Example: let's assume I need to extract all possible combinations of objects described in a text. The model is quite good in returning most of them, but forgets some. When it asks "is thee anything else I should consider?", I want to be able to answer "You forgot to include all combinations when person X goes to place Y". After 2/3 iterations of this process, I'm always able to converge to the correct solution on the ChatGPT interface, but completely fail using Langchain (i'm trying with a ChatOpenAI model).

Does anyone know of a tutorial where something similar to this is explained? Or, do you have any tip on how something like this could be achieved? (my goal is to go from an unstructured text, to a structured one, which lists all possible combinations of possible events. Then, I want to pass the structured text to an agent that generates a set of combinations in a list using the Python REPL tool). Any tip on how to do this/ where to look?

What I'm trying now is to use the "Human" tool of the agent, but the questions it asks are not even close to be the correct ones.